# Stopping QPushButton From Indenting

Tags: c++, qt, button

I would like to stop a QPushButton from indenting when clicked and instead just change it's background colour.

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A solution, which is easy to put in place (but might not provide *exactly* what you want) would be to use [Qt Style Sheet](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html).

With style sheets, you can specify a background color for the [pressed state](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html) of the button. Doing this will suppress the indent. For instance :

```
pMyPushButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton:pressed { background-color : red; }");
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as stopping the indent, I think you can do setFlat as documented here:
http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qpushbutton.html#flat-prop

Comment: This still has an indent on click.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to subclass QPushButton and override its paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) method with your own implementation that gives it the look you want to give it.

Alternatively, you could create a subclass of QCommonStyle (or QWindowsStyle or etc) and pass it qApp->setStyle(), and override the drawControl() method so that when drawControl is called with element CE_PushButtonBevel, it would call up to the superclass using a separate QStyleOptionButton argument that doesn't include State_Sunken or State_On bits set.  (It would probably take a bit of examination of the superclass's drawControl() method to figure out exactly what is necessary to get the effect you want).

Answer (score 0):

It helped me to just set the `padding:` property in the stylesheet.

```
QPushButton *cmd = new QPushButton();
cmd->setStyleSheet("padding: 0px;");
```

the value is somehow not relevant. `0px` have same effect as `4px`. I don't know why.

set pressed properties like that:

```
cmd->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background: blue; padding: 0px;}"
                   "QPushButton:pressed {background: orange;}");
```

in addition I set `border: 1px solid black; outline: none;` - just in case this is relevant to.